# PlacesApi get business type within a radius of lat lon

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using the following library for accessing a few location APIs from Google

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

I see methods such as below that accept two parameters

```
 PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(context, location)
```

But I don't see any method for getting a business type within a radius of lat lon.

If we use the URL directl like below

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + lat + "," + lng + "&radius=100000&type=hospital&name=hospital&key=MYKEY
```

Any way to use the library instead of the URL above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can use the [Java client library](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) to get results like in web service request.

Have a look at the following code snippet that explains how to use this library

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey("AIza......")
                .build();

NearbySearchRequest req = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(context, new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(41.385064,2.173403));
try {
    PlacesSearchResponse resp = req.keyword("pizza")
       .type(PlaceType.RESTAURANT)
       .radius(2000)
       .await();
    if (resp.results != null && resp.results.length > 0) {
        for (PlacesSearchResult r : resp.results) {
            PlaceDetails details = PlacesApi.placeDetails(context,r.placeId).await();

            String name = details.name;
            String address = details.formattedAddress;
            URL icon = details.icon;
            double lat = details.geometry.location.lat;
            double lng = details.geometry.location.lng;
            String vicinity = details.vicinity;
            String placeId = details.placeId;
            String phoneNum = details.internationalPhoneNumber;
            float rating = details.rating;
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error getting places", e);
}
```

So, once you created request object you can provide keyword, type and radius and send request.

I hope this helps!